# Trying to convert integer object which is in a class to a string

Tags: java, class, tostring

I am trying to convert integer object which is in a class to a string. When the CreateAccount() is printed without adding any variable to phone_number, I want it to print "No info". But phone_number is needed to stay integer in general.

```
public class CreateAccount {
    
    private String customer_name;
    private int phone_number;
    private int password;
   
   
    public void CreateAccount(){
        this.customer_name = "No info";
        Integer.toString(this.phone_number);
        this.phone_number = "No info";
```

When I am trying to convert phone_number to string with using Integer.toString(), it is giving the "String cannot be converted to int" error.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct line? `this.phone_number = "No info";` is more likely causing that message.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase, so no underscores.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use proper java semantic and as been told you messed up with the types

```
public class Account {
        
    public int phoneNumber;
    public String customerName;

    public Account(int phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.customerName = phoneNumber != 0 ? String.valueOf(phoneNumber) : "No INFO";
    }

    public int getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn I didn't understand anything about "this.customerName = ..." part. I think I am in way over my head as a beginner. Thanks for your answer, I will skip that problem for now...

Comment: this is a shortcut for this if(phoneNumber != 0){this.customerName=String.valueOf(phoneNumber);} else {this.customerName="No INFO";}